# Retain Custom Attributes & Methods of Pandas Series SubClass when assigning to DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a function that does an ETL to a list/Series and returns a Series with additional attributes and methods specific to that function.  I can achieve this by creating a class to extend the Series and it works but then when I try to reassign the output from the function with the new class the updated class attributes and methods are stripped away.  **How can I extend the Series to have custom attributes and methods that are not stripped away when reassigning back to the dataframe?**

### Custom function that does ETL, returns a Series with an extended class

```
import pandas as pd

def normalize_x(x: list, new_attribute: None):
 
    normalized = pd.Series(['normalized_'+ i if i != 4 else None for i in x])
    
    return NormalizeX(normalized = normalized, original = x, new_attribute = new_attribute)


class NormalizeX(pd.Series):

    def __init__(self, normalized, original, new_attribute, *args, **kwargs,):
        super().__init__(data = normalized, *args, **kwargs)

        self.original = original
        self.normalized = normalized
        self.new_attribute = new_attribute


    def conversion_errors(self):

        return [o != n for o, n in zip(pd.isnull(self.original), pd.isnull(self.normalized))]


df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "C": ['dog', 'cat', 4]})
```

### Assign to a new object (new attributes and methods work)

```
out = normalize_x(df.C, new_attribute = 'CoolAttribute')

out
## 0    normalized_dog
## 1    normalized_cat
## 2              None
## dtype: object

## Can still use Series methods
out.to_list()
## ['normalized_dog', 'normalized_cat', None]

## Can use the new methods and access attributes
out.conversion_errors()
## [False, False, True]
out.original
##0    dog
##1    cat
##2      4
##Name: C, dtype: object
```

### Assign to a Pandas DataFrame (new attributes and methods break)

```
df['new'] = normalize_x(df.C, new_attribute = 'CoolAttribute')

df['new']
## 0    normalized_dog
## 1    normalized_cat
## 2              None
## dtype: object

## Can't use the new methods or access attributes
df['new'].conversion_errors()
## AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'conversion_errors'
df['new'].original
## AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'original'
```

Comment: I think this person is asking for a similar thing https://stackoverflow.com/q/69292599/1000343

Comment: Would it be better/easier to store these extended Series in a dictionary than a datafame? Are you going to use implemented pandas methods on these extended series as well?

Comment: Yes my intent was to use the pandas methods on them

Comment: You might need to use the actual ExtensionArray/ExtensionDtype API to get everything working properly in a DataFrame. Pandas provide an extensive pytest suite to ensure expected behavior. Even a minimal ExtensionArray takes quite a bit of code to pass the fixtures. See my answer here for a complete example: [**Simple example of pandas ExtensionArray**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972163/13138364)

Answer (score 8):

Pandas allows you to extend its classes (Series, DataFrame). In your case, the solution is quite verbose, but I think it's the only way you have to reach your goal.

I try to get to the point without analyzing complex cases, so the complete implementation of the interface is up to you, but I can give you an idea of what you can use.

I don't understand the utility of *new_attribute*, so for the moment is not taken into account. Basically, Pandas extensions let you extend only a 1-D array as far as I know. Since you have multiple arrays (both *normalized*, *original*) you have to create another data type to get around the problem.

```py
class NormX(object):
    def __init__(self, normalized, original):
        self.normalized = normalized
        self.original = original

    def __repr__(self,):
        if self.normalized is None:
            return 'Nan'
        return self.normalized
```

This allows you to create a simple base object like the following:

```
norm_obj = NormX('normalized_dog', 'dog')
```

This object will be the **basic block** of your custom array. To be able to exploit this kind of class, you have to **register** a new **type** in Pandas:

```py
from pandas.api.extensions import ExtensionDtype, register_extension_dtype
import numpy as np

@pd.api.extensions.register_extension_dtype
class NormXType(ExtensionDtype):
    name = 'normX'
    type = NormX
    kind = 'O'
    na_value = np.nan
```

Now you have all the elements to build a custom array based on Pandas framework. To do that, you have to extend its interface class named `ExtensionArray`. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray.html#pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray) you can find the abstract methods that must be implemented by subclasses. I gave you a very basic implementation, but it should be declared in a proper way:

```
from pandas.api.extensions import ExtensionArray

class NormalizeX(ExtensionArray):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.data = values
        
    def __repr__(self,):
        return "NormalizeX({!r})".format([(t.normalized, t.original) for t in self.data])
    
    def _from_sequence(self,):
        pass
    
    def _from_factorized(self,):
        pass
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]
    
    # def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    #     self.normalized[key] = value
    #     return self
    
    def __len__(self,):
        return len(self.data)
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False
    
    def dtype(self,):
        # return self._dtype
        return object
    
    def nbytes(self,):
        return sys.getsizeof(self.data)
    
    def isna(self,):
        return False
    
    def take(self,):
        pass
    
    def copy(self,):
        return type(self)(self.data)
    
    def _concat_same_type(self,):
        pass
```

Moreover, to define a custom method on that class, you have to define a [custom Series accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.register_series_accessor.html), as follows:

```py
@pd.api.extensions.register_series_accessor("normx_accsr")
class NormalizeXAccessor:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.normalized = [o.normalized for o in obj]
        self.original = [o.original for o in obj]
        
    @property
    def conversion_errors(self):
        return [o != n for o, n in zip(pd.isnull(self.original), pd.isnull(self.normalized))]
```

In this way, the `NormalizeX` custom array implements all the requested methods to be successfully integrated into both Series and DataFrame. So, your example  reduces to:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "C": ['dog', 'cat', 4]})
norm_list = [['normalized_'+ i, i] if i != 4 else (None, i) for i in df.C]
normx_objs = [NormX(*t) for t in norm_list]
normalizedX = NormalizeX(normx_objs)

df['new'] = normalizedX

# Use the previously defined attribute_accessor normx_accsr
df['new'].normx_accsr.conversion_errors # [False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's too difficult for me to implement your desired functionality, so I only share what I found in my investigation expecting it might be useful for other answerers.

### The cause of the issue:

The reason why you got those attribute errors is sanitization processes were carried out on the `Series` which you passed to the `DataFrame`.

### A brief check of `id`s:

You can quickly confirm the difference between what `out` and `df['new']` refer to by the following code:

```py
out = normalize_x(df.C, new_attribute = 'CoolAttribute')
df['new'] = out
print(id(out))
print(id(df['new']))
```

```
1861777917792
1861770685504
```

you can see `out` and `df['new']` are different from each other because of this `id` difference.

Let's dive into the pandas source code to see what goes on here.

### `DataFrame._set_item` method:

In the definition of the `DataFrame` class, [`_set_item`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.3.x/pandas/core/frame.py#L3774-L3797) method works when you try to add `Series` to `DataFrame` in a specified column.

```py
    def _set_item(self, key, value) -> None:
        """
        Add series to DataFrame in specified column.
        If series is a numpy-array (not a Series/TimeSeries), it must be the
        same length as the DataFrames index or an error will be thrown.
        Series/TimeSeries will be conformed to the DataFrames index to
        ensure homogeneity.
        """
        value = self._sanitize_column(value)
```

In this method, `value = self._sanitize_column(value)` in the first line except the docstring. This `_sanitize_column` method actually destroyed your original `Series` functionality. If you dig this method deeper, you'll finally reach [the following lines](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.3.x/pandas/core/frame.py#L10767-L10771):

```py
def _reindex_for_setitem(value: FrameOrSeriesUnion, index: Index) -> ArrayLike:
    # reindex if necessary

    if value.index.equals(index) or not len(index):
        return value._values.copy()
```

`value._values.copy()` is the direct cause of the disappearance of the `NormalizeX` attributes. It just copies the values from the given `Series`.
Therefore, the `_set_item` method should be modified in order to protect the `NormalizeX` attributes.

### Conclusion:

You have to override the `DataFrame` class to set your `NormalizeX` in a specified column keeping with its attributes.